# In CoreData,how to get rid of objects with nil value on specified column

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I am using NSPredicate to filter NSManagedObject.What I want is retrieving objects which have non-null value on specified property,so,how to create the NSPredicate instance? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite simple:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"yourProperty != NULL"];
```

should to the trick.